# why my sql server profiler only showing me blank template

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-profiler

I am new to this SQL server profiler stuff. I am trying to create a trace in sql server profiler. when i tried to select the template it is showing me only blank and no name of template can anyone tell me why

Comment: Could you post a screen shot?

Answer (score 2):

By default, SQL Server Profiler templates are stored here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Profiler\Templates\Microsoft SQL Server
```

Within this folder, you will see sub-folders for different SQL Server versions (80,90,100,1050). It could be that you are trying to connect your profiler to a server running a higher release.

Check this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/b5a0c106-faf6-4a21-a012-2d60366190e3/

> "The server you are connecting to is a 10.50 sql server and your
>   machine doesnt have a folder for that. So to fix it, copy your 100
>   folder (found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Profiler\Templates\Microsoft SQL Server\100) making a
>   new folder in the same location named 1050."

Comment: Thanks, creating a new folder `1050` and copying the templates from the `100` folder worked.